# Como fazer uma tabela do SQL Server ler corretamente textos UTF8

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma query no qual eu preciso fazer a coluna `Name` ler códigos UTF8.

Eis o código aqui:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MonsterList](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [EffectID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MonsterList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Já tentei mudar o `varchar` para `nvarchar`, acontece que essa query puxa arquivos .txt com nomes de "Monstros" é de um game.

Porém, quando traduzo estes monstros utilizando acentuação como por exemplo: Cão, Ação, etc..., a coluna `Name` ou não puxa os nomes, ou quando puxa ele buga o código.

Existe uma maneira de eu deixar essa query lendo códigos UTF8 ou ANSI corretamente com acentos?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Seu problema é o COLLATION na tabela...

Teste com o COLLATION Latin1_General_CI_AS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Efetuei a alteração do collation no create table, porque uma vez não explicito o collation é o padrão do database.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo, você pode efetuar a query convertendo os campos char,varchar e/ou nvarchar (strings), mas dependendo do caso terás perdas de performance!

Esse link pode lhe ajudar!

https://www.sqlshack.com/the-collate-sql-command-overview/